# How to use a Arduino Due in a CMake-based package using rosserial-arduino?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosserial-arduino, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I prefer using the CMake-based approach for packages using rosserial-arduino as not requiring the Arduino IDE has quite a few advantages. For the older Arduino boards, specifying the board type is as simple as typing it somewhere in the CMakeLists.txt, e.g. (example from [here](https://github.com/skohlbr/simple_2wd_robot/blob/master/simple_2wd_control_arduino/firmware/CMakeLists.txt#L10)):

```
generate_arduino_firmware(controller
  SRCS controller.cpp ../lib/AFMotor.cpp ${ROS_LIB_DIR}/time.cpp
  BOARD uno
  PORT /dev/ttyUSB0
)
```

It appears to be a bit more complicated for the Due however, as that one is special and not a "classical" avr device (see [location-of-boards-txt-for-an-arduino-due-sam-board on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799214/location-of-boards-txt-for-an-arduino-due-sam-board) for instance).

My question is: Is it possible to "painlessly" compile and flash firmware for the Due using a CMake setup, or is it required to manually copy and setup the `boards.txt` for that one somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290333/how-to-use-a-arduino-due-in-a-cmake-based-package-using-rosserial-arduino?/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2018-05-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2018-05-14**:
Just found http://answers.ros.org/question/225519/arduino-due-cmake-with-rosserial_arduino/ ,which pretty much is the same question, but asked 2 years ago. No really useful answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened an issue on the rosserial github regarding this ([see rosserial #370](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/issues/370)). Unfortunately, at this point in time, the Due is not supported. Adding it would mean integrating a newer fork of arduino-cmake.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1